# How to retrieves all rows from a subquery

Tags: sql-server

I am a beginner in SqlServer. I have a table that contains values and their IDs :

```
IDMark |  Mark
 1        Dell
 2        Sony
```

and another table Essai that contains a SerialNumber and the Mark :

```
SerielNumber | Mark
  DF34F        Dell
  34RTB        Dell
```

The table above had 133 rows.

I want to insert into another table all the 133 rows's Ids mark, something liek this

```
SerialNumber  |  Mark
  DF34F          1
  34RTB          1
```

I have used a subquery, but it retieves only undiplicated rows. It's like a distinct, it return only 2 rows. This is my query

```
select idMark from Marque where mark in (select mark from ESSAI)
```

It returns only two rows
Also how can I insert the result into my new table ? should I use a procedure or a fetch ?? I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need a join, something like this:

```
select SerielNumber, idMark from Marque m
JOIN essay e ON m.mark=e.mark
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked, No I want to insert these values in another table I did this, but it didn't work `insert into Materiel (serviceTag,idMarque) values ((select serviceTag from ESSAIEIMPORT),(select idMarque from MarqueMateriel mm, ESSAIEIMPORT ess where mm.marque = ess.marque))
` it's showing an error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.` how can I solve this

Comment: insert into Materiel select serviceTag, idMarque from MarqueMateriel mm, ESSAIEIMPORT ess where mm.marque = ess.marque

Comment: "values" is a word to insert a bunch of scalar values and insert one and only one row.  you omit this word when you're using a "select" from another source of data.

Answer (score 0):

is this what u searching?
insert into Materiel (serviceTag,idMarque) select a.servicetag,b.idmarque from essaieimport a join marquemateriel b on a.marque=b.marque